# Converting a Webform application to MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am converting an ASP.NET WebForm application into an ASP.NET MVC application and being new to MVC, I am trying to make sure I do this right.

Currently, in my WebForm application, it is AJAX powered using jQuery and doing calls to WebMethods in the C# code behind. Currently, how the WebForm works now is there might a page with a few fields that need to be filled out and saved to the database. To do this, we'd have an HTML form and a save button. When the button is pressed, this javascript function is called:

```
function SaveForm()
{
    if (!ValidateForm())
        return;

    ShowWaitingOverlay();

    var params = {};

    params.firstName = $('#<%= txtFirstName.ClientID %>').val();
    params.lastName = $('#<%= txtLastName.ClientID %>').val();
    params.address1 = $('#<%= txtAddress1.ClientID %>').val();
    params.address2 = $('#<%= txtAddress2.ClientID %>').val();

    // ... many more just like above

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Hosts.aspx/SaveHost",
        data: params,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(msg) {
            HideWaitingOverlay();
            if (msg.d == "0") {
                alert("Save Failed!");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

This function would do an AJAX call to an ASP.NET Web Method that might look similar to this:

```
[WebMethod]
public static string SaveForm(string firstName, string lastName, string address1, string address2)
{
    var host = new BusinessLayer.HostApplication();

    host.FirstName = firstName;
    host.LastName = lastName;
    host.Address1 = address1;
    host.Address2 = address2;

    host.Save();

    return host.HostId.ToString();
}
```

Of course there are other irrelevant details omitted for brevity, but this is the general idea.

My question is, what would be the correct "MVC way" of converting this? I would think a lot of this code would go away and/or be hidden in the data model. I wouldn't think it would be necessary to have to need all the lines that assign each individual textbox/dropdown, etc to the `params` variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have an action method that get a [`DTO`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object) object and returns a Json result. In this action method, you could call the business layer to proceed the flow. For sample:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SaveForm(CustomerDTO input)
{
   var host = new BusinessLayer.HostApplication();

   host.FirstName = input.FirstName;
   // oth properties

   host.Save();

   return Json(new {success = host.HostId != 0});
}
```

and your DTO could be:

```
public class CustomerDTO 
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    // other properties
}
```

In the client-side, you could try this:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "@Url.Action("SaveForm", "ControllerName")",
        data: $("#formId").serialize(),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(result) {
            if (result.success)
            {                
                HideWaitingOverlay();
            }
            else 
            {
               alert("Save Failed!");
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: I wouldn't want to decorate it with an `[HttpPost]` though, right? Since I don't want to do a postback, right? I want to call it from Ajax.

Comment: Well, I saw into your ajax request you want to do a POST, so, that's the attribute you need. I think it is a good pratice when send information to be saved in server, instead keep this method as a `GET`.

Comment: I did some edits about the client-side, but, i'm not sure if it is right in your scenario, but, that's the path. You post into server and get the response into the argument of success function.

Comment: Its looking better. Do I still need to add a line like `params.firstName = $('#<%= txtFirstName.ClientID %>').val();` for every field on my form?

Comment: You could try to call the serialize() method, take a look at my edits.

Comment: I didn't even know jQuery had a `serialize()` method. Good Find!